# Ubuntu default `sources.list` causing `sudo apt-get update` to fail

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I've been having some issues with my packages and repositories, so I decided to try and reset my `sources.list` file. I did so by removing it from the command line, creating a blank in its place, and using Ubuntu's Software & Updates GUI to try and remake it. This however, seems to have created new problems. When I try to run `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following output:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]  
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
Hit:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com bionic InRelease        
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease            
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB] 
Hit:6 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                   
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                 
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [260 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [517 kB]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [197 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [97.6 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [446 kB]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [193 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                     
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is here. My goal is to just reset the repository list to the factory default for stability and re-add things as they become necessary, but it seems that the default configuration isn't working well.

Comment: A quick opening of http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/ in a browser (or you could just read it's name) tells you it supports TRUSTY or Ubuntu 14.04.  Ubuntu 18.04 provides bionic (18.04) sources not from other releases, and **not** PPAs that are not audited or reviewed in the ways the main/universe/restricted/... repositories are. Your stated aims do not match what you've done at all in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the default configuration. It seems like you didn't wipe the sources lists in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the error messages and as far as I can tell, did exactly as I hoped it would.